# Why does a simple click function not find the selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I am writing a really quick js module that opens up and image and fades out a container to show the image. The markup for the image is this below:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:1px;" class="rsNavItem rsThumb front">
    <div class="rsTmb portfolio">
        <img src="http://www.mysterium.ch/revelation/pictures/revelation_highres_06.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now what happens is the click basically fades out a div and then shows the container.

```
loadSlide: function () {

            console.log('clicked');

            //$('.rsThumb').each(function () {
                var containerT = $('.rsnav-container'),
                containerB = containerT.find('.rsThumb');


            $('.rsThumb').click(function (e) {

                console.log('clicked again');

                e.preventDefault();

                var sliderObject = $('.collection #gallery-t-group').data('royalSlider');

                var s = this;

                // Lets make sure the body is activated
                $('body').addClass('rsSlider-active');

                $('.loader').show().transition({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 100, 'easeInOutQuart');

                // $('.socialbar-vertical-static').removeClass('activestate');

                $('.body').transition({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 100, 'easeInOutQuart');

                // After slider loads
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.body').transition({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 500, function() {
                        $('.loader').transition({
                            opacity: 0
                        }, 500).hide();
                    });

                    theSliderActivated();
                    theSocialActivated();

                    sliderObject.updateSliderSize(true);

                    $('div#container').css('margin',0);
                }, 1000);

            });
            //});
        }
```

The script is also loaded in at the top like so:

```
init: function() {

            var app = this;

            this.fakingIt();
            this.loadSlide();
            this.unloadSlide();
            this.mobileNav();
            this.loadThumbs();
            this.royalSlider();
            this.thumbsSwitch();
            this.functionResize();
            this.theSocialActivated();
            this.slideEventChange();

            console.log('======> new.global.js');


        }
```

For some reason it will not register the event at all and even with a console log after the click nothing registers at all.

Am I doing something really wrong here?

Comment: Is there a typo in the selector?   containerB = containerT.find('.rsThumb'); and here <div class="rsTmb portfolio">

Comment: mh..just went over it quickly. am i right, that your click function can only be handled while "loadSlide()" is running? (which is 1000ms)?
@AlexDenysenko the parent container of that div has the class rsThumb. should be right.

Comment: Hi razhial yeah thats right loadSlide(); is the function

Comment: are you using ajax to load the div `rsThumb` ?

Comment: I think that Krishna has the right idea. Use the .on() function to listen to elements which are added after the initial function is called.

Comment: tried .on and this does not work...

Comment: @Mdunbavan - just using `.on()` doesn't do it. Event delegation needs to be handled on a static outer container. for your example, try if this works `$(document).on('click','.rsThumb', function (e) {`

Comment: Hey Krishna, that worked. Thanks I should have done doc ready. I did that but in a normal function :/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are definitely calling init() from within a document ready event handler. This will ensure the rsThumb div is available when binding to its click event.

```
$(function(){
    init();
});
```

Comment: Hi Tom I use this: `$(document).ready(function () {new global();});` at the end to register all scripts to run at the end and then at the top I use `var global = function() { this.init(); };` so it creates the init there

Comment: `this` from within the `global` function will refer to the global function itself. Is that also where `init` is defined?

Comment: Hi Tom here is a codepen of the script and exactly how it looks, the funny thing is that fakePj function works just fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BeHLh

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing parenthesis between lines 145 and 147.

Comment: That does not matter as its at the end of the code line so, if there was a code error with the syntax I would get an error and with the code I see no errors at all in the console.

Comment: I've added the missing bracket and commented out the calls to theSliderActivated() and theSocialActivated(), which don't exist, and commented out sliderObject.updateSliderSize(true), which fails as well, and I've added an alert on click. The click is firing as requested. http://jsfiddle.net/8PRv2/

Comment: hmmm this seems to not be working for some reason. Do you want to see the whole script with all functions etc?

Comment: Erm, yep sure, post it up somewhere. Can you not see the working code in the fiddle in my last comment? Did you try adding the bracket, or was that a mistake in the codepen link code only?

Comment: Tom the answer was above, I had to attach the .on click handler to the document for that selector.